# JQuery event to fire when a drop down is selected -- but the value is not changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu that I want to connect a JQuery event to that fires if someone clicks on it but then selects the same option that is already selected.

I've got everything running using the 'change' event but there are cases where it's valid for the user to click the dropdown and reselect the same option. If that occurs I need my event handler to fire.

How can I do this?

Comment: show us your HTML and jquery code please

Comment: Why not use the 'click' event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers do not seem to provide a solution that both handles all edge-cases (such as clicking outside of the dropdown and then clicking on it again) and/or avoids double events triggering.

The first trick is to store the value from the moment the dropdown is focused. The default change() event is used to trigger the method `changewithRepeats` when the dropdown value has changed, as normal.

Otherwise, a second click on the focused element will call blur(), forcing a defocus and triggering `changewithRepeats` if and only if the dropdown value remains the same as initially.

Opening the dropdown and cancelling out of it is not possible, this is intentional. Any defocus will call the method. All keyboard interactions also work (*but the call to blur() when selecting the same value will be slightly annoying for users with screenreaders*).

Focus state in the below is 0 = unfocused, 1 = when getting focus, 2 = has focus.

```
$(function () {
  var lastFocusValue = '';
  var focusState = 0;

  var changeWithRepeats = function (newestValue) {
    // Your change action here
  };

  $('select').click (function () {
    if (focusState == 1) { focusState = 2; return; }
    else if (focusState == 2) $(this).blur();
  }).focus(function (e) {
    focusState = 1;
    lastFocusValue = $(this).val();
  }).blur(function () {
    focusState = 0;
    if ($(this).val() == lastFocusValue) {
      // Same value kept in dropdown
      changeWithRepeats($(this).val());
    }
  }).change (function () {
    changeWithRepeats($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Fiddle has some more debug outputs: https://jsfiddle.net/dsschneidermann/tb5csdhp/15/

Comment: After 6 years finally someone actually answers the question correctly. I've moved on to other things, but the thousands of developers that will read this later will appreciate it. Hats Off! to you sir!

Answer (score 8):

Try something like below,

Using `.click`

```
$(function () {
    var cc = 0;
    $('select').click(function () {        
        cc++;
        if (cc == 2) {
            $(this).change();
            cc = 0;
        }         
    }).change (function () {
        $('#result').append('Changed triggered ');
        cc = -1;
    });     
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/NAHXP/2/

Or using `.focus` and `.blur`

```
$(function () {
    var ddVal = '';
    $('select').focus(function () {
        ddVal = $(this).val();
    }).blur(function () {
        if (ddVal == $(this).val()) {
            $(this).change();
        }
    }).change (function () {
        $('#result').append('Changed triggered ');
    });       
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/NAHXP/

Comment: On both of the jsfiddles I can click on 'test1', then click away from the drop down and then click and reselect 'test1' -- and change is not triggered. Is this what you intended? I need change to trigger.

Answer (score 4):

Use focus and blur events...

```
var selectValue;
$('select').focus(function(){
   selectValue = $(this).val();
}).blur(function(){
  if (selectValue == $(this).val()) {
     //nothing change event
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is click solution

```
var oldValue = null;
$('select').click(function(){
  s = $(this);
  val = s.val();
  if (oldValue == null) {
      oldValue = val;
  } else {
      oldValue == s.val() ? alert('nothing changed') : alert('new value');
      $(document).unbind('click.valueCheck');
      oldValue = null;      
  }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/wLWMc/)

Here is more advanced solution with document click extended

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/wLWMc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

use add class to solve this problem

```
 $("#test").change(function(event){
 if($(this).find('option:selected').hasClass('actived'))
   alert('already selected');//write you code here
 else
   $(this).find('option:selected').addClass('actived');

});
```

and refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/muthukumar0705/nARVu/1/

Comment: If the 'change' event does not fire, does this work? My issue is the change event is not firing.

Comment: No is not work without change event. Can you explain little bit more.

Comment: If you select an option, then go back and select the *same* option later -- I still need the event to fire.

Comment: then you need to handle selected data with browser cookies or database . without store it is not possible

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I'm simply trying to get an even to fire -- I could use local storage for information but if I can't get an event to fire then I'm not sure what I would use it for.