# jQuery not behaving as expected with this select element

Tags: jquery

I have this code that opens a popup window when the first item in the dropdown list
is selected.

```
<select id="selectItem">
    <option value="newItem">Load new item...</option>
    <option value="ddsds">first item  </option>
</select>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#selectItem").change(function(){
        if($(this).prop("selectedIndex") == 0){
            window.open('popup.html', '_blank', 'scrollbars=1, height=600, width=500');
        }
    });
 });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVRHY/)

If I select an item different than the first one, then selecting the first item will open the popup window.

But if the first item is selected whitout selecting any other item before, the popup windows doesn't launch.

I don't get what is happening. How should I properly tell jQuery to open the popup
when the first option is selected?

**EDIT:**

I was misunderstanding the change event. As many people mentioned, the popup won't fire when the selection isn't changed. 
Maybe I will use a button to replace the current "business logic".

Comment: The change event fires ... wait for it ... when the input *changes*

Comment: "the first item is selected whitout selecting any other item before" - then is it really "selected"?

Comment: hi @jtheman just test the page. Select the first option, and the popup will not launch.

Comment: No I can't select it as its already selected. In your code you are using the change() event. For this to work the select need to change!

Comment: See my suggestion below. Try using blur() instead of change() http://jsfiddle.net/wVRHY/8/

Comment: Just a side note: `$(this).prop("selectedIndex")` is the same as `this.selectedIndex` but slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Information:** Obviously when you first click the first item it shouldn't display the popup because otherwise there is no way a user will be able to see all the other options. As a result the following code will allow you to click the first option to view all options and then when you select the first item it will work as you require.

**Solution:**

```
var cc = 0;

$('#selectItem').click(function ()
{
  cc++;

  if (cc == 2) 
  {
    $(this).change();
    cc = 0;
  }
}).change(function (){
  if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") == 0)
  {
    window.open('popup.html', '_blank', 'scrollbars=1, height=600, width=500');
  }

  cc = -1;
});
```

**Credit:** I got most of the code from  ["Vega's Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002651/1550441) and then added extra code to suit your answer.

Comment: thanks @MVCKarl, I just saw your answer and this code does what the question is asking for! Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dW2wq/

Answer (score 2):

Like Andy Ray commented - this is expected behavior for the *change* event - it won't fire when the selection isn't changed.

One option is to simply add an option (no pun intended) to the select, so that the "load new" isn't selected by default;

**html**

```
<select id="selectItem">
    <option selected>please pick</option>
    <option value="newItem">Load new item...</option>
    <option value="ddsds">first item  </option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$("#selectItem").change(function () {
    if (this.value === "newItem") {
        window.open('popup.html', '_blank', 'scrollbars=1, height=600, width=500');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wVRHY/6/

BUT -- depending on what your form is supposed to do i suspect you are **probably better off with a `<button>`** for your 'load new...' functionality

Answer (score 1):

You need to add window.open method also outside the change event so that it will run when page is loaded.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#selectItem").change(function(){
            if($(this).prop("selectedIndex") == 0){
                window.open('popup.html', '_blank', 'scrollbars=1, height=600, width=500');
            }
        });
    if($("#selectItem").prop("selectedIndex") == 0){
                window.open('popup.html', '_blank', 'scrollbars=1, height=600, width=500');
            }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wVRHY/2/

Comment: thanks Özgür but when I select the first option, the popup doesn't still launch at all. I have to select any other option first and that is not what I want

Comment: thanks Özgür, but I really need the popup to be opened when the user selects the first option, the one that says "Load new item". Maybe I'm misunderstanding the change event. I'll try with trigger event.

Comment: @Lucas I see. This one actually works http://jsfiddle.net/wVRHY/2/. But got caught by popup blockers. To avoid this you can use a button and use click() event to trigger the actual event.

Answer (score 1):

You will need use the `load` event to check the status of the option once the page has loaded - or you could manually `trigger` the change event.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

Actually for your example using `blur()` instead of `change()` would work.

```
$("#selectItem").blur(function(){
        if($(this).prop("selectedIndex") == 0){
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wVRHY/8/

Comment: That won't do anything until the select loses focus. Also makes popup blockers more likely to block it.

Comment: @xec I agree but he wants the popup to show also when the select has not actually changed and I can't think of another trigger than blur for that. mouseup() for instance will be to jumpy. Why would a popup blocker be more strict on the blur() event than the change() event? Its still just a js popup...

Comment: I just tested in firefox and the popup got blocked from inside the blur event, but not the change event. I'm not sure what the logic behind this behavior is though :) In any case it's not a viable solution because the issue outlined in the question is not fixed (clicking on the selected option will not do anything).

Comment: I agree both with xec and Lucas - xec's solution is clearly what you would want and I also suggest a button or similar instead of making the select have different behaviour for different options, this is not a good interface solution. I was just trying to match your need, and as it seemed in the beginning you was looking for blur not change.