# Simulating user clicks using JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

Yesterday, I asked a question in stackexchange and Sean and A. Wolff have already gave satisfying answer to what I was asking. [The link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335522/simualating-user-clicks-using-javascript-or-jquery/27338484#27338484) The issue was that there is an overlay on top of the dropdown menu which makes it not visible if there is change on it. We removed that overlay and it worked.

I continued working on my project today and I realized that the question that I asked and therefore the answers are not exactly what I want. What I want is that, I really want to have the exact user clicks. This means that, we should not remove any class or element from the page while we are achieving our goal.

Here is a minimalist code. There is a dropdown menu and if you select the "Bedrag" in the menu, there is a text box opens next to the dropdown. Could anyone help me how I can select the "Bedrag" using JQuery or JS? Please note that, no elements or classes or whatever should be removed. It should just select the item in the dropdown and trigger the signal. I have been trying a lot with this but it boiled down to the point that I can't do it without any help from you guys.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/so0h96ns/1/

The code for the dropdown is:

```
<div data-custom-select class="select-price ">
  <label for="price" data-label-hide class="has-hidden-label">Selecteer prijs</label>
  <select name="adv.bedragplaats" id="price" class="price-field" data-price data-set-as-required >
    <option value="">Kies...</option>
    <option value="&lt;amount&gt;" >Bedrag</option>
    <option value="gratis" >Gratis</option>
    <option value="ruilen" >Ruilen</option>
    <option value="teab" >Prijs overeen te komen</option>
    <option value="nvt" >Niet van toepassing</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's three parts

```
        //first assign the change event which opens the box on the side
        $('.price-field').on("change", function () {

            if ($(this).val() === "<amount>") {
                console.log("the amount option has been selected now open THE BOX");
            }

        })

            //then select the bedrang
                .find('option[value="<amount>"]')

            //then trigger the change event to open the box
                .attr("selected", true).trigger("change");
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/orchid1/vtrsgLnr/1/

Comment: Hi Edgar. Thanks for your time & reply. However, if I run your code, it doesn't select the "Bedrag"? Am  I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks again, but again we come back to the issue that I mentioned in my text above. In your example, you took the isolated snippet. Therefore you don't have this overlay thing. when I try your code, it doesn't even set the dropdown value. Well, it does, but apparently in the background. My actual question is how to trigger the right signals after setting the item value using .find('option[value="<amount>"]'); Apparently .attr("selected", true).trigger("change"); doesn't do that. Here is my code, http://jsfiddle.net/so0h96ns/3/
Do you agree with what I am saying? Thanks.

Comment: here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/orchid1/vtrsgLnr/1/ the box on the side will open once you add the code inside the change event as in the code above.

Comment: Still a question remains. You say that I need to add code inside of the change event to open the box. Can we do it the same way when I click on the dropdown menu as a user does in the website? I mean, I feel that we reinvent the existing code since the box already open when clicked. This is what I am really trying to achieve. Just like normal user clicks.

Comment: instead of "change" event then just use  "click" event. i.e. .trigger("click") thats the only way you can do it.

Comment: I have already tried it. It doesn't also do anything. Or again I do something wrong.