# Move focus to next field if user doesn't change the option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML Select list as follows:

```
<div class="somebox" id="somebox">
     <select name="myoptions" id="myoptions">
        <option value="1">Some Text 1 </option>
        <option value="2">Some Text 2 </option>
        <option value="3">Some Text 3</option>
        <option value="4">Some Text 4 </option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="somename1" id="somename1">
      <input type="text" name="somename2" id="somename2">
</div>
```

And Have some JavaScript code, which moves the focus to the next element on change of #myoptions.

```
$("#somebox").on("change", "#myoptions", function(){
   $("#somename1").focus()
});
```

The question is: 
 - How can I move the focus to the next element if user just clicks on the `select` list, checks other options in the list but doesn't change the option? 
(In this case, focus lies there on the same `select`, because user doesn't change the value)

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8n6rmsx7/) created.

**Note**- In our code `tab` key is disabled, so quite hard for user to move the focus to the next element.

Comment: Why is the `[tab]` key disabled? o.O

Comment: Thats clients requirement, They wanted to use the `tab` only to navigate through tabbed pages .

Comment: you mean even you didn't change the option, you still want the focus go to next element?

Comment: @huanfeng : Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you wanted?

```
var cc = 0;

$('#somebox').click(function () {
    cc++;
    if (cc == 2) {
        $(this).change();
        cc = 0;
    }
}).change(function () {
    $("#somename1").focus();
    cc = -1;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/8n6rmsx7/2/)

I found there is a similar thread talking about this:
[useful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002421/jquery-event-to-fire-when-a-drop-down-is-selected-but-the-value-is-not-change)

Comment: :- Thanks for workaround for me! Worked like a charm :)