# Need an event to fire when selecting index in dropdown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need an event in JavaScript which will fire when something is selected from dropdown. I am using `onchange` now, it does almost everything I want, but when I am clicking my dropdown and select index that was already selected, it won't fire. And I need an event that acts like `onchange`, but fires every time even when I am selecting already selected option.

Is there something like that in JS?

Comment: Why don't you use `onclick` instead??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery event to fire when a drop down is selected -- but the value is not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002421/jquery-event-to-fire-when-a-drop-down-is-selected-but-the-value-is-not-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want something that is already answered in another question.

[JQuery event to fire when a drop down is selected -- but the value is not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002421/jquery-event-to-fire-when-a-drop-down-is-selected-but-the-value-is-not-change)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002421/jquery-event-to-fire-when-a-drop-down-is-selected-but-the-value-is-not-change
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try with other events, such as 'onclick' on the options of your dropdown, or 'onblur' on the dropdown.

Oh, I've found this for you: https://jsfiddle.net/49md3116/1/

Here the html:

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Here the javascript, with JQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $("#dropdown").on('mouseleave', function(e){
      console.log($('#dropdown').val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use onclick instead of onchange.